# VB import value from text

Tags: vb.net, text-files, text-parsing

Let's say I have for example a simple three line text file where is stated for example:

```
FirstName=Adam
LastName=Smith
Age=25
```

but there are more files with different value and/or are scrambled that the LastName is first, FirstName is second etc. so the app must not be dependant on the line number but instead read words from the text.

I want that app to get into file, detect that the Adam is first name, Smith is last name, that the age is 25 and output it as a strings that then get imported and immediately assigned to appropriate in-app variable (LastName=Smith gets assigned to LastName variable in App etc.).

I hope you understood me.. it is hard to explain :-). I can try to provide further explanation if u can't get what I really want.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please read [how to ask](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to add a [complete and verifiable](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of what you tried. Also include the desired results.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to do but I would start by putting the data in a dictionary or a proper class. After you figure that part out, you can look at importing in the system.

Comment: Do you know how to open a file and read it? If not search for that and try some code. If your code fails, show us that and what error or bad result you are getting.

Comment: Yes I know how to open and read files as a whole using My.Computer.FileSystem.Readalltext or the StreamReader, however I don't know how to get the exact partition of that text - so it reads the text file, detects that First Name is Adam and imports that as a FirstName equals Adam into the app, same with LastName=Smith etc etc. I don't want that to be predefined I want app that can read and store data and I have absolutely no idea what commands I should use and I don't know how could Collection,Classes or Dictionaries help me with that.

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service.  If you need someone to write an application for you, there are paid services for that purpose.  If you insist on doing it yourself, but you don't understand how to create a simple algorithm, that is far too broad of a topic for a Q&A format.

Comment: Sorry I wrote that wrong way. I don't want application to be written for me - I don't even want an applicaton I just wanted to expand my knowledge and what I wrote is an example... I want to know if it's even possible and if so then what command serves for that so I could use it in my future projects.

Comment: The only thing I could find out is that app gets to read entire text with Readalltext and if it finds out for example the FirstName it will copy the whole line and then put another code to remove the first 10 letters (including the equals sign) so only the value stays here and then it gets attached to variable Firstname inside of app but that is too much complicated and it would have to be counted for every thing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some string functions. What you need are [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2). `Substring` is used to get a certain part of the string. `IndexOf` is used to get a location of a certain part in a string. So you need to get where the equal sign is then separate the string before and after the equal sign. The one before the equal sign is the property name while the one after the equal sign is the property value.

```
Sub Main

    Dim firstName As String = "", lastName As String = "", age As Integer
    For Each line In File.ReadLines("C:\input.txt")
        Dim equalSignIndex = line.IndexOf("=")
        Dim propertyName = line.Substring(0, equalSignIndex)
        Dim propertyValue = line.Substring(equalSignIndex + 1, line.Length - equalSignIndex - 1)
        Select Case propertyName
            Case "FirstName" :
                firstName = propertyValue
            Case "LastName" :
                lastName = propertyValue
            Case "Age" :
                age = propertyValue
        End Select
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("Name = {0} {1}, Age = {2}", firstName, lastName, age)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible answer, using `line.Split` that may be appropriate. I've took into account that the formatting of your text file may be a little messy so I've made a text file `input.txt` as a test, its contents are like so:

```
FirstName=Adam
LastName=Smith
Age=25 
lastName=Smith2
FirstName=Adam2
Age=35 
age=45 

Firstname=Adam3
LastName=Smith3
firstname=Adam4
LastName=Smith4
Age=55 

FirstName=Adam5
LastName=Smith5
Age=65
```

As you can see, I've intentionally put some things in the wrong order, added line breaks and also messed with the character casing for good measure.

Code:

```
    Dim firstName As String = String.Empty, lastName As String = String.Empty, age As Integer = 0

    For Each line In File.ReadLines("C:\input.txt")
        If line.Contains("=") Then
            Dim TxtSplit() As String = line.Split("="c)
            Select Case TxtSplit(0).ToLower
                Case "firstname" : firstName = TxtSplit(1)
                Case "lastname" : lastName = TxtSplit(1)
                Case "age" : age = Integer.Parse(TxtSplit(1))
            End Select
        End If

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) AndAlso Not age = 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}, Age: {2}", firstName, lastName, age)
            firstName = String.Empty : lastName = String.Empty : age = 0
        End If
    Next
```

The FirstName, LastName, Age will only be printed to Console once each has its value. So it will pass the check, write to console, then variables will reset ready the the next set of three. Hope that's of help.

Console output From above:

```
Name: Adam Smith, Age: 25
Name: Adam2 Smith2, Age: 35
Name: Adam3 Smith3, Age: 45
Name: Adam4 Smith4, Age: 55
Name: Adam5 Smith5, Age: 65
```

Comment: Thank you guys! Finally someone who actually understood what I am trying to say :). Gotta try that when I get home.

Comment: Yes! Tried that in multiple cases, always worked :) now I want to try it on arrays so u have something like Qualifications {job1;job2;job3..} .. to get multiple different outputs.. that is my vision for future :D. Anyway thank you for your help:)

Comment: Glad to know it worked. Why didn't you mark my answer as answered?